# When does convergence in distributions inply convergence in covariance?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence, correlation, uniform-integrability

Good Morning.
Let $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n$ be sequences of random variables converging in distribution respectively to $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $X_n,Y_n$ are equally distributed but dependent for all $n$, while $X,Y$ are equally distributed and independent. 
Is it true that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

In my specific problem I also have that $X_n$, $Y_n$ and $X_nY_n$ are uniformly integrable. The thing is that I don't know if the joint variables $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ in distribution.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$ X_n\sim \frac{1}{2}\delta_{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_1$$ and $Y_n=X_n$,  then $$ X,Y\sim \frac{1}{2}\delta_{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_1.$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $$ (X,Y)\sim \frac{1}{4}\delta_{(-1,-1)}+\frac{1}{4}\delta_{(-1,1)}+\frac{1}{4}\delta_{(1,-1)}+\frac{1}{4}\delta_{(1,1)}.$$
But $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are dependent, in fact, $$(X_n,Y_n)\sim \frac{1}{2}\delta_{(-1,-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{(1,1)}.$$
Clearly $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not converge in distribution to $(X,Y)$.